# Drawing circles of different size in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I use ECSY library (https://ecsy.io/) to generate particles (for example, 100) in canvas. I'm trying to make those particles have different size but it changes only after refreshing the page. What am I doing wrong? How make them draw with different sizes?

```
const SHAPE_RANDOM_SIZE = 20 - 20 * Math.random();

let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
let canvasWidth = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
let canvasHeight = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
...
// drawing circle
drawCircle(position, size) {
            ...
            ctx.arc(x,
                    y,
                    size,
                    0,
                    2 * Math.PI,
                    false);
            ...    
}
...
drawCircle(coords, SHAPE_RANDOM_SIZE); // coords is an object with required coordinates x and y
```

Comment: Is there any other code that you are missing that may help? If you want to generate different sizes then you will need to create a for loop that runs for however many circles you want. Then in every iteration of the loop you will need to generate a random size and draw a circle.

Comment: To add on @Chris. You are creating a random size once. That size is used for every circle. Create random sizes for every circle.

Answer (score 0):

To give you a code sample of what I'm suggesting from my comment, I'm going to add as an answer.

If you want to draw many circles with different sizes, then you will need to create a loop that runs for however many circles you want. Then in every iteration of the loop you will need to generate a new random size and then draw your circle. Ideally you would also pass in random coordinates, although I'm not sure what the rest of your app is like.

```
const numberOfCircles = 25;

for (let i = 0; i < numberOfCircles; i++) {
    // generate a random size for EVERY circle
    const randomSize = 20 - 20 * Math.random();

    drawCircle(coords, randomSize);
}
```